# Detecting changes on entities in contex of asp.mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have very standart scenario. I send entity from controller to view for user to edit it. User pushes submit button I get entity back from browser in my controller. Its detached now so I attach it back to context. How can I detect if there were changes made compared to database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pull the entity back from the database when the user submits.  There are a number of reasons you can't know for certain what to do just by looking at what came back:

1. Can't trust data from the user.  The user has full control over what the browser sends back to you, so this is a possible exploit if you key off something in the request
2. Another user might have modified the same data

Pulling an entity from the database is fast, so just pull it, set the fields you want to set and SaveChanges()

Addition:  As Eduard noted in the comments below, it looks like there is a utility method `ApplyCurrentValues` to do this: [msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd487246.aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd487246.aspx)

Comment: So you say rather then attaching entity and then changing state to modified and calling `saveChanges()` to load the entity again and copy every single field to original db entity? That feels so clumsy...

Comment: How will entity framework know which fields were modified if you just attach and save?  Also, you might have to deal with modifying mapping tables and navigational properties.  I don't see it as clumsy.  You probably need to do validation anyways against values on the entity, and without pulling it from the database, you can't know what that state is.

Comment: May be I found what I was looking for `ObjectContext.ApplyCurrentValues<TEntity> Method` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd487246.aspx after aplying this method original entity will change state to modified if there were some properties changed. Thats how Ill know that entity has changed compared to database....

Comment: @Eduard, that's basically a short cut to do what I said.  You still need to get the entity from the database before modifying it with that.

Comment: I agree but mentioning the ApplyCurrentValues method would be helpful ;). Anyway +1

Comment: @Eduard, I'll edit my answer.  Note that I didn't no about the ApplyCurrentValues and am glad to know about it;)